# Kafka 2.1 behaviour change for retentions and Kafka Stream application, what can we so that retention works?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Following is from the Kafka Documentation for 2.1.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/

```
Offset expiration semantics has slightly changed in this version. 
According to the new semantics, offsets of partitions in a group will 
not be removed while the group is subscribed to the corresponding 
topic and is still active (has active consumers). If group becomes 
empty all its offsets will be removed after default offset retention 
period (or the one set by broker) has passed (unless the group becomes 
active again). Offsets associated with standalone (simple) consumers, 
that do not use Kafka group management, will be removed after default 
offset retention period (or the one set by broker) has passed since 
their last commit.
```

If I understand this correctly, as long as Stream Thread consumer's are connected, no retention setting will be effective?

I also started to observe following Exception after the restart of stream application

> stream thread - Restoring Stream Tasks failed. Deleting StreamTasks stores to recreate from scratch. 
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions:' but stream application uses the property 'StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG), "earliest"'...

I think it has to do something with retention but I can't tell what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I understand this correctly, as long as Stream Thread consumer's are connected, no retention setting will be effective?

This applies to `__consumer_offset` topic only, that is a Kafka internal topic. For all regular/user topics, retention time is applied the same way as in all previous versions. Also note, this only applies if you upgrade your brokers to `2.1`.

For the log message of Streams: you don't need to worry about it. It seems that your application was offline for a longer time, and thus, your local store is not in a consistent state any longer. Thus, it's deleted and recreated from scratch from the changelog topic.